# How to use "com.azure" package for azure java sdk

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

It's specified in this page https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java,

`Java 8 or later is required to use libraries under the com.azure package, for libraries under the com.microsoft.azure package Java 7 or later is required.`

Does that mean I should add dependencies like

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
      <version>1.31.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not `<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>` anymore?

Well, I downloaded this sample, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Hybrid-resources-java-manage-resource-group.git, and changed all `com.microsoft.azure` to `com.azure`, but it did not work...

Comment: This might help:  https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/2020-03/java.html#installation-instructions

Comment: Thanks.  But how do I find out the equivalent classes?  Do they have more documents?

Answer (score 0):

The `azure` artifact is part of `com.microsoft.azure` group. So, you should continue to use this group. See https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure/1.31.1/jar

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
  <version>1.31.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The new packages released under `com.azure` group follow [new design guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/java_introduction.html).

You can find more details on all available packages (old and new) [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java#available-packages).

> ### Available packages
>
> Each service might have a number of libraries available from each of
>   the following categories:
>
> - Client: New Releases
> - Client: Previous Versions
> - Management: New Releases
> - Management: Previous Versions
>
> #### Client: New Releases
>
> New wave of packages that follow the [Azure SDK Design Guidelines for
>   Java](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/java/guidelines/) and share a
>   number of core features such as HTTP retries, logging, transport
>   protocols, authentication protocols, etc., so that once you learn how
>   to use these features in one client library, you will know how to use
>   them in other client libraries. You can learn about these shared
>   features
>   [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/core/azure-core/README.md).
>   These libraries can be easily identified by folder, package, and
>   namespaces names starting with `azure-`, e.g. `azure-keyvault`.
>
> You can find the **[most up to date list of all of the new packages on
>   our
>   page](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/index.html#java)**.
>   This list includes the most recent releases: both GA and preview.
>
> > NOTE: If you need to ensure your code is ready for production use one of the stable, non-preview libraries.
>
> #### Client: Previous Versions
>
> Last stable versions of packages that have been provided for usage
>   with Azure and are production-ready. These libraries provide similar
>   functionalities to the new libraries, as they allow you to use and
>   consume existing resources and interact with them, for example: upload
>   a blob. Previous library directories start with `microsoft-azure-`,
>   e.g. `microsoft-azure-keyvault`. They might not implement the
>   [guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/java_introduction.html)
>   or have the same feature set as the new releases. They do however
>   offer wider coverage of services.
>
> #### Management: New Releases A new set of management libraries that follow the [Azure SDK Design Guidelines for
>
> Java](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/java/guidelines/) are now in
>   Public Preview. These new libraries provide a higher-level,
>   object-oriented API for *managing* Azure resources, that is optimized
>   for ease of use, succinctness and consistency. You can find the list
>   of new packages [on this
>   page](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/java.html) .
>   Documentation and code samples for these new libraries can be found
>   [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/management)
>
> > NOTE: If you need to ensure your code is ready for production use one of the stable, non-preview libraries.
>
> #### Management: Previous Versions For a complete list of management libraries which enable you to provision and manage Azure resources,
>
> please check
>   [here](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/java.html).
>   They might not have the same feature set as the new releases but they
>   do offer wider coverage of services. Management libraries can be
>   identified by namespaces that start with `azure-mgmt-`, e.g.
>   `azure-mgmt-compute`

For a full list of all Azure SDK releases, check [this page](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this section](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/#management-new-releases) on Java releases.

Note that the newer version of com.azure.resourcemanager:azure:azure-resourcemanager is still in preview stage. You do not want to take it into your production system, yet.

If you do not intend to use resourcemanager lib with other com.azure libs, you can safely continue using com.microsoft.azure:azure until above get GAed.